# Most practical way to parse WKT strings to get array of points?

Tags: javascript, wkt

I'm using open layers to `zoomToExtent` so I can auto center my screen on a set of randomly placed geometries.

I'm using some hacky regex that doesn't cover a lot of edge-cases and wondering if there is something in javascript to help parse WKT strings for me.

Example:

```
POLYGON ((35 10, 45 45, 15 40, 10 20, 35 10),
(20 30, 35 35, 30 20, 20 30))
```

Yields:

```
[[35,10], [45,45], [15,40].....
```

I've been looking at Turf, but haven't found anything they can do to solve this.

Comment: https://github.com/mapbox/wellknown provides a parser for WKT and produces GeoJSON, which should help you get the coordinates you need.

Comment: @forrert I'm looking for something MIT

Comment: If you are using OpenLayers you can covert with `coordinates = new ol.format.GeoJSON().writeGeometryObject(new ol.format.WKT().readGeometry(wktString)).coordinates;`